# Photos App is not showing left navbar / folders/volumes navigators

Tags: photos.app

As can be seen there is no leftnav in the *Photos* app anymore.

[image]

I'm not sure what I did to cause it to disappear (after years of no issues).  How can I get it back?  There's no obvious way in the Menu:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely controlled by the *width* of the *Photos* app.  I had made it more narrow and the left-nav automatically disappeared. Widening again and it comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Uncheck the option "Always show Toolbar and Sidebar in full screen" and restart the app

I don't know why "Yours & Shared" greyed out in yours

Comment: Tried that - no change